# Unreal4 beam particle source location moving with bone/socket

Tags: unreal-engine4, particle-system, unreal-blueprint

I am following this tutorial to create a very simple particle system.https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hjgnqkLeqf0

Now I want to make the lightning source moving with my character's right hand. There is nothing in parameter instance so I'm guessing I should use blueprint.

Here is my level blueprint and my particle source settings.

What I was trying to do is

1. I created a socket on skeleton called weapon.
2. get the socket position in run time every tick.
3. update particle parameter "lightning source point" vector every tick.

I can see that I get updated socket location from "Get Socket Location" every tick, but my particle source won't move. I also tried add Bone/Socket module in particle cascade but not working(works fine with regular particle but not beam data I guess)

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved by attaching the emitter to the socket in character blueprint, not level blueprint.